# Javascript: constructing html element IDs programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

I need to access the values of a number of fields in my page and perform the same calculations on them. I would like to do something like this, allowing me to dynamically access different form elements, but I cannot get it to work:

```
function numInFamily(famID) {
    var numAdults;
    var numChildren;
    var adultFieldID;
    var childFieldID;

    adultFieldID = 'numAdultsFam' + toString(famID);
    childFieldID = 'numKidsFam' + toString(famID);

    numAdults = parseInt(document.getElementById(adultFieldID).value,10);
    numChildren = parseInt(document.getElementById(childFieldID).value,10);

    return numAdults + numChildren;
}
```

Could anyone explain how I can dynamically reference these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in `toString` global function. But you don't need such a function, since the `+` operator does the string conversion automatically. Just replace the first two assignments with this:

```
adultFieldID = 'numAdultsFam' + famID;
childFieldID = 'numKidsFam' + famID;
```

---

Also, you can rewrite the function like so:

```
var numInFamily = (function () {     
    function getVal ( id ) {
        return parseInt( document.getElementById( id ).value, 10 );
    }

    return function ( famID ) {
        return getVal( 'numAdultsFam' + famID ) + getVal( 'numKidsFam' + famID );
    };    
}());
```

This will remove the code repetition.

Comment: loved the 5 different versions of your answer you posted... :)

Comment: @trex005 Hehe, I keep improving it until I'm satisfied.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas- thanks! The problem was indeed with the toString(). Changing that alone solved the issue. I appreciate the further guidance on streamlining the code as well.